# SearchKit: identify current Memberships where last recurring payment or instalment is too old

Tags: recurring-contributions, searchkit

I would like to construct a query in SearchKit - if it is possible - that answers the question:
"Find active (Current, New) Memberships where Contributions recur monthly and the last Contribution was more than one month ago.", and separately,
"Find active Memberships where Contributions recur annually and the last Contribution was more than one year ago".
This would be enormously helpful in trapping situations where recurring payments have failed for a variety of reasons. Before SearchKit, there was no hope (it seems) of finding these Memberships without a large set of search strategies, but with SK, the possibility of a simple solution looks tantalisingly close...

Answer (score 1):

Are you dealing with failed recurring contributions or simply contributions that don't exist?

If it's failed recurring contributions, you can do:

- Memberships
- Where Recurring Contribution is not empty and Status is
  one of Current, New
- Without Membership Recurring Contribution where Number of Failures is greater than 0

If it's that contributions don't exist, you could do:

- Contacts
- with Memberships where Recurring Contribution is not empty and Status is one of Current, New
- without Contributions where Recurring Contribution is not empty, date in range last 30 days, and Status = Completed

This assumes your contacts don't have other recurring contributions.

Comment: Thank you @Lars - I think I have been able to construct the Failed Payments version, but I'm struggling with the Missing Payments. I can't see how this distinguishes between monthly and annual payers?

Comment: You should be able to add a where for Frequency Units for the Recurring Contribution, assuming your annual ones are all one year as opposed to 12 months (or if you need to cover 12 months too, then you can add Interval).